# Let A be an n*n matrix and let v be a nonzero vector such that Av=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

And it can conclude that the the set of rows of A matrix is linearly dependent.

I know that it can express as

[image]

so the set of columns of A matrix is linearly dependent.
however, I have no idea how to prove the set of rows of A matrix is also linearly dependent.

Comment: The matrix $A$ and its transpose share the eigenvalues. Here, the eigenvalues is zero.

Comment: What have you tried and what definitions are you using? There are many equivalent ways to tackle this. One of which is $Av = 0$ and $v \neq 0$ implies $\ker{A} \neq \{0\}$, which implies that the columns are linearly dependent, which implies that the rows are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2 x 2 matrices such as the one you are using there is an easy proof.

If all the elements of the matrix are zero then there is nothing to prove. So suppose without loss of generality that $a_1\ne 0$. You know that the columns are linearly dependent and so the second column is a multiple of the first. Let the matrix be $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & ta_1 \\ a_3 & ta_3\end{bmatrix}$.

It is now obvious that the second row is $\frac{a_3}{a_1}$ times the first row.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows: if $Av = 0$ has a non-zero solution $v = (v_1,v_2)$, then $A$ does not have an inverse.  So, $\det(A) = 0$.  So, $\det(A^T) = \det(A) = 0$.  So, $A^T$ also doesn't have an inverse, which means that $A^T$ has linearly independent columns, which is to say that $A$ has linearly independent rows.